# change user input before POST to django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to get user input, do something to it, then pass it to the Django server. Here is my code.

**JS**

```
 frm = $("#textCSVForm");
        frm.submit(function(event) {
            console.log('submit');
            $.ajax({
                    url: frm.attr('action'),
                    type: frm.attr('method'),
                    dataType: '',
                    data: {
                        test: 'post via js passed'
                    },
                    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .done(function(response) {
                    console.log("success");
                    //  console.log(response);
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    console.log("error");
                })
                .always(function() {
                    console.log("complete");
                });
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<form id='textCSVForm' class="" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{from}}
    <button name='' id="textCSV" type="" name="">Via CSV text</button>
</form>
```

**forms.py**

```
lass GetNewData(forms.Form):
    JSONTransactions = forms.CharField(initial = initialText, widget = forms.Textarea, label='Update with data', max_length=600)
```

After I am done working with the user input, I place it on the `data: {test: 'post via js passed'}` section. The problem is that the user input gets sent before the changes take place. Is there a way to do this while still using Django's form system?

Comment: I think you are submiting you form before the ajax. You should add `event.preventDefault()` (at the line after `frm.submit(function(event) {`). And also check your `data` on AJAX. You should take the all the form variables here.

Comment: @Rafaelyes that is exactly happening ill try ur suggestion 

Comment: @Rafael TY sir! worked like a charm 